# Как в PostgreSQL выводить нули?

Tags: postgresql

В таблице есть столбец, где должны находиться трёхзначные цифры (начиная с 000, заканчивая 999). При выводе информации с БД заметил, что столбцы: 000, 001, 002 и т.д. выводят лишь один символ: 0, 1, 2 - соответственно. Как сделать так, чтоб находящиеся в столбце нули также выводились?

Comment: Если вывод идёт на клиент, то там эти нули и формируйте, чего напрягать БД зазря

Comment: to_char(int, text)  -> to_char(123, '999') или LPAD(123,3,'0')

Comment: @АлексейШиманский круто, конечно, звучит, но я пока не познал настолько великую силу)

Comment: @Виктор, а где вводить переменную с запросом? Типо $query. 
Извиняюсь, если вопрос глупый, просто новичок пока в этом

Comment: select LPAD(column_name,3,'0') from table

Comment: Трёхзначная цифра - само по себе могуче... всё же трёхзначное - это число. Но увы, ведущие нули у чисел всегда отсутствуют, и для того, чтобы они появлялись, надо переводить числовое значение в строковое. Ну и тут, как выше правильно сказано, либо используйте соотв. выражение в SELECT, либо форматируйте на клиенте. Ещё вариант - вычисляемое поле, но он мне кажется для такой задачи избыточным.